# Получить список точек для построения квадртатов

Tags: python

Никак не могу что то сообразить.
Есть список точек (X,Y). которые образуют некую сетку.

```
points = [ (0, 0), (0, 2), (0, 4), (2, 0), (2, 2), (2, 4), (4, 0), (4, 2), (4, 4) ]
```

[image: Список точек]

Мне необходимо из этих точек получить список точек, которые образуют квадрат.
Т.е. на выходе я пытаюсь получить такой формат:

```
rectList = [[(0, 0), (0, 2), (2, 0), (2, 2)], [(0, 2), (0, 4),(2, 2), (2, 4)], [(2, 0), (2, 2), (4, 0), (4, 2)]]
```

Вот такие квадраты мне необходимо получить(цветом выделил, чтобы было более наглядно):

[image: Список квадратов]

Comment: второй список [(0, 2), (0, 4)] из двух точек... так должно быть?

Comment: Цветом выделен только один квадрат (синий в правом нижнем углу). так что более понятно не стало

Comment: Нет. ошибочка, исправил, точек должно быть 4.

Comment: Цвета просто накладываются друг на друга, я их пронумеровал дополнительно. Нужно получить что то вроде шахматной доски, то есть такие квадраты

Comment: Самые маленькие? Ориентированные по осям?

Comment: ага, самые маленькие

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто обходите по строкам и по столбцам

```
n = 3
rectList = []
points = [ (0, 0), (0, 2), (0, 4), (2, 0), (2, 2), (2, 4), (4, 0), (4, 2), (4, 4) ]
for i in range(n-1):
    for j in range(n-1):
        rectList.append([points[i * n + j], points[i * n + j + 1], points[(i + 1) * n + j + 1], points[(i + 1) * n + j]])
print(rectList)
```

Comment: Вы полагаетесь на порядок точек в списке?

Comment: @Stanislav Volodarskiy Да, иначе ведь нужно задавать размер и искать

Comment: то, что нужно, спасибо!

Comment: Я к тому что если порядок известен, то координаты не нужны. :). Другими словами, ТС надо бы решать другую задачу.

Comment: @Stanislav Volodarskiy Ну ему нужно было соотнесение точек и квадратов, а о фактической необходимости этого не буду судить.